# I have an unexpected token error. Where is it coming from?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm being told there is an unexpected token error in my mapStateToProps function, but I'm failing to find it. Can you take a look and tell me what the problem is?

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

const mapStateToProps = state =>({
  config: state.config,
  receipt: { receiptProducts = [] },
  expeditedShipping: state.expeditedShipping.expeditedProduct
})

@connect(mapStateToProps)
```

The error from my computer reads...

```
ERROR in ./src/client/app/cbd-
mobile/components/receipt/ReceiptComponent.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected , (8:26)

   6 |   config: state.config,
   7 |   receipt: { receiptProducts = [] },
>  8 |   expeditedShipping: state.expeditedShipping.expeditedProduct
     |                           ^
   9 | })
  10 | 
  11 | @connect(mapStateToProps)

 @ ./src/client/app/index.jsx 31:24-83
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 
./src/client/app/index.jsx
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`receipt: { receiptProducts: [] }` instead of `receipt: { receiptProducts = [] }`

You would typically use `{ x = [] }` when setting a default value for unpacking

```
const { x = [] } = someVariable
```

in this case, though, you're just building a javascript object, so you only use `:`s